# how to add a control in inherited Datagridview control WPF

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have inherited a `Datagridview`  for an `UserControl`, now I want to draw a `ListBox` below a cell, please help me how to do this.

in ordinary windows .net app i use this

```
public class MyControl : Datagridview
{
  Listbox Lst = new Listbox();
  this.controls.Add(Lst);
  Lst.visible= false;

 //in Beginedit event
 //I make visible Lst below the requited cell
}
```

In WPF please tell me how to do this. 
 I use DataBound DataGrid in wpf.

Comment: what do you mean by "below a cell" ?

Comment: Are you aware of `DataGridTemplateColumn` ?

Comment: `MyControl : Datagridview` where do you take that `Datagridview`? WPF don't have such control.

Comment: If you are using WPF, you should be using DataGrid.